# Usage of spring application index

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

Can someone please clarify what is the usage of `spring.application.index` property and why do we need it?

Application.yml:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: ServiceName
        index:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I see, the `spring.application.index` has been considered deprecated since the version `2.0.0.RC1`. I judge from comparing the following these appendices:

- Spring Boot `2.0.0.M7`: [Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties) where the `spring.application.index` is mentioned.
- Spring Boot `2.0.0.RC1`: [Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties) where the `spring.application.index` is not mentioned.

The previous statement is proved by inspecting the source codes of the `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer` across these versions:

- Version `2.0.0.M7` [ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java). These versions provide more variability in customization the application index used for ApplicationContextID creation.

  ```
  /**
   * Placeholder pattern to resolve for application index. The following order is used
   * to find the name:
   * <ul>
   * <li>{@code vcap.application.instance_index}</li>
   * <li>{@code spring.application.index}</li>
   * <li>{@code server.port}</li>
   * <li>{@code PORT}</li>
   * </ul>
   * This order favors a platform defined index over any user defined value.
   */`"${vcap.application.instance_index:${spring.application.index:${server.port:${PORT:null}}}}"`
  ```
- Version `2.0.0.RC1` [ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java).
  There could be find the index is incremented using automatically using `AtomicLong`, which also assures its uniqueness. See the inner `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer$ContextId` class for more detail in the source. The key method is its constructor:

  ```
  ContextId createChildId() {
      return new ContextId(this.id + "-" + this.children.incrementAndGet());
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you!, so if I understand correctly, this property is not relevant anymore from 2.0.0.RC1?

Comment: Indeed. The Spring keeps creating it automatically anyway, you are just no longer involved. The `AtomicLong` usage assures uniqueness of the generated index.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this property in [Spring sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer.java):

```java
private static final String INDEX_PATTERN = 
"${vcap.application.instance_index:${spring.application.index:${server.port:${PORT:null}}}}";
```

As the Javadoc of this class says, it is used to create ApplicationContextID which is a unique id of an application context.